# values at x-axis fall in between xtics

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a graph where the x-values fall in between xtics.

For example, I want my xtics to be

> C72 C73 C74 C75 C76 C77 C78 C79 C80 C81

and the points fall in between C72  C73 ; C73  C74 ; C74 C75 ; and so on.

My data points are

```
>  2.5  0.17509   C72  
>  3.5  0.220434  C73   
>  4.5  0.164918  C74  
>  5.5  0.172477  C75   
>  6.5  0.156145  C76  
>  7.5  0.171699  C77   
>  8.5  0.165199  C78   
>  9.5  0.191207  C79   
> 10.5  0.211656  C80  
> 11.5  0.202233  C81
```

I used xticlabels() in the script definitions as below:

```
#OUTPUT    
set terminal pngcairo size 650,450 enhanced dash
set output "xplot_gauche_malto-thermo.png"
set style line 4 lt 4 lw 10 # Please DISABLE pause -1 

#MICRO
set macro
labelFONT="font 'arial,22'"
scaleFONT="font 'arial,18'"
scaleFONT2="font 'arial,18'"
keyFONT="font 'arial,18'"

# AXIS DEFINITIONS
set xrange [0:12]
set yrange [0:0.8]
set xtic (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)                @scaleFONT2 
set ytic                                        @scaleFONT                      
set boxwidth 0.8
set size square  

#PLOT 

plot "all_dihedrals_in_layers_malto.dat" using 1:2:xticlabels(3) with linespoints lw 2 linecolor rgb "black" pointtype 1 pointsize 2 title ""
```

If I use the code as above, to get a plot using only column 1 and 2 from data file (as given above) I get the points fall in between 2-3, 3-4, 4-5 and so on.

Unfortunately if I use "xticlabels()", I don't get the graph as I wanted where the point supposed to fall in between C72-C73, C73-C74, C74-C75 and so on.

Appreciate in advance for any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try something like this..  (Untested i dont have gnuplot on this machine..)

```
plot "all_dihedrals_in_layers_malto.dat" using 1:2 with linespoints \
        lw 2   linecolor rgb "black" pointtype 1 pointsize 2 title "" ,\
     "all_dihedrals_in_layers_malto.dat" using ($1-.5):0/0:xticlabels(3)
```

of course you could alternately manually key in the labels on the set xtics line..

Edit..had a chance toi try it, the 0/0 or (0/0) does not work. What you need to do is plot some value out of range.. eg:

```
set yrange [0:]
plot "all_dihedrals_in_layers_malto.dat" using 1:2 with linespoints \
        lw 2   linecolor rgb "black" pointtype 1 pointsize 2 title "" ,\
     "all_dihedrals_in_layers_malto.dat" using ($1-.5):-1:xticlabels(3) notitle
```